# Linking CSS to HTML using Aptana Studio 3

Tags: html, css

I want to link my css code with the html code for my website. I am using Aptana Studio 3. It appears to work, but when I preview it in Aptana my css styling does not show up. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>jampens</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div align="left">
<a href="about.htm">About</a> &nbsp;
<a href="contact.htm">Contact</a> &nbsp;
<a href="products.htm">Products</a> 
</div>
<div align="center">
<h1>JAM Pens</h1>
<div>
<p>Welcome to the official website of JAM Pens.</p> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css code:

```
.body {
font-family: cursive;
 }
```

When I preview it, the css style doesn't show up. 
All my files are saved in the same folder so I don't know why this is not working. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

.body refeers to a container with a body class, if you want to be applied to the body tag remove that dot

```
body { font-family: cursive; }

.some its applied to class="some"
#some its applied to id="some"
some its applied to <some></some>
```

Comment: Even after removing the dot the styling is not appearing.

Comment: Title tag it's also inside head tag, have you tried with a more visible tag like background-color: #f00; I haven't used Aptana in a while, also try it in a browser, to check the link it's working propperly

Comment: Thanks! I tried it in Firefox and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the font family in the body.
Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>jampens</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div align="left" class="navagation">
<a href="about.htm">About</a> &nbsp;
<a href="contact.htm">Contact</a> &nbsp;
<a href="products.htm">Products</a> 
</div>
<div align="center">
<h1>JAM Pens</h1>
<div>
<p>Welcome to the official website of JAM Pens.</p> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
.navagation{
  font-family: cursive;
}
```

Comment: Actually you can, if you want to be applied to all the body